# How to use CVPixelBufferCreate to create a black CMSampleBufferRef?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need a black `CMSampleBufferRef` to test.
I use this code. But it is a white `CMSampleBufferRef`.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer=NULL;
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1280, 720, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, NULL, &pixelBuffer);
CMSampleTimingInfo info ={ kCMTimeInvalid, kCMTimeZero, kCMTimeInvalid };
CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDesc=NULL;
CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, &formatDesc);
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer=NULL;
CMSampleBufferCreateReadyWithImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         pixelBuffer,
                                         formatDesc,
                                         &info,
                                         &sampleBuffer);
```

How to use CVPixelBufferCreate to create a black CMSampleBufferRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this after your code, it would fill the pixel buffer with black pixels:

```
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    UInt32* buffer = (UInt32*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < width * height; i++ )
    {
        buffer[i] = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(0x000000ff);
    }
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```